# How to access Point Coordinates

Tags: c++, winforms, mouseevent

Just starting out with GUI Windows programming. I'm working in Visual Studio C++ Wondows Forms.

I've figured out how to grab the mouse coordinates and dump them into a double Point coordinate variable but when I try and access the the X & Y values to manipulate them I get...

```
error C2248: 'System::Drawing::Point::x' : cannot access private member declared in class 'System::Drawing::Point'
```

The Point variable is called firstPoint and I'm trying to access the values using firstPoint.X  and firstPoint.Y.  I guess that's not the correct way to go about it.

How do I go about converting the values into an int so I can mess with it?  Convert::ToInt32(firstPoint.x) is what threw the errors.

Google searches keep sending me to pointer topics not Point Coordinate topics.

Additional code as requested:

```
private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    unsigned char ucRed, ucGrn, ucBlu;
    bool drawing;
    Point firstPoint, finalPoint;
    //int iShape, iX1,iY1,iX2,iY2;

private: System::Void panel1_Paint_1(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) 
     {
        Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;

 //create an ellipse with
 //  Black color
 //  start position = firstPoint mouse coordinate
 //  width = difference between firstPoint and finalPoint, height = difference between firstPoint and finalPoint


        g->DrawEllipse(Pens::Black,firstPoint.x,firstPoint.Y,(finalPoint.X-firstPoint.X),(finalPoint.Y-firstPoint.Y));
```

Comment: Not familiar with the Point class but you are trying to access a private member, hence the message. look for this class getters and you will probably find what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the public properties X and Y with captial letters(Note: case sensitive), x and y are the private member variables of the struct.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx

Convert::ToInt32(firstPoint.X)